# from the claims of sweeping fraud

Tags: word-meaning

I don't understand the use of "from" here.  In the past, she prosecuted crimes like theft and assault, which is easy to understand. But the structure of the sentence seems to mean "prosecuted...from the claims of sweeping fraud", which is not understandable to me.

What does "from" mean here?  It appears to have some sense of "just like" - But I am simply guessing, not sure of it.

> Jenna Ellis broke into the legal profession in 2012 as a deputy district attorney in Weld County, Colo., a largely rural area that would soon make headlines for a failed attempt to secede from the rest of the state because some residents resented the growing dominance of more liberal communities to the south like Denver. Ms. Ellis prosecuted crimes like theft and assault, felonies of a different magnitude **from the claims of sweeping fraud** and criminal conspiracy she makes today as a top lawyer to President Trump.

> Source: [NYTimes](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/12/03/us/politics/jenna-ellis-trump.html?action=click&module=Top%20Stories&pgtype=Homepage)

Comment: It means that the felonies are based on the claims of the fraud cases.

Comment: @DhanishthaGhosh no it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you.  So it implies that she acts not strictly based on law?  Rather, she is based on conspiracy theories.  (Edited: I just saw Daniel Roseman's comment. Now reconsidering the meaning...)

Comment: I first thought it would be the variety (range) suggesting from fraud cases to something, where the to phrase is missing. Perhaps?

Comment: Yeah I agree. Something appears to be missing there.

Comment: No. The phrase is fine as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, "from" does not correspond to "prosecuted". The relevant phrase is "a different magnitude from".

It's clearer if you break it into two:

> Ms. Ellis prosecuted crimes like theft and assault. These felonies were a different magnitude from the claims she makes today.

In other words, when she started out she was prosecuting small crimes; but now she's on a completely different scale as she's prosecuting the [completely made-up] claims of election fraud.

Comment: That's very clear now. Thank you.